# URL query string parameters are not getting shown in the url on clicking <a> in PHP

Tags: php

I have added three query string parameters in the url of the link

```
$path13 = "Jobtype.php?skill=$s1&jobtype=$value5&Allloca=$l1";
echo "<a href= $path13><option value=$path13 Selected>$value5</option></a>";
```

but it is not showing the values in the url for $_GET after clicking on it.

it goes to the mentioned page url but with incomplete information: Jobtype.php?skill=&jobtype=Work.

i have mentioned Allloc=$l1 also in the url path but it is not showing in the url after going to the mentioned url

Comment: An `<option>` element can only be a child of a `<select>`

Comment: Hi, when i click on the SELECT tag and OPTION tag's <a> it goes to the said url but incomplete: Jobtype.php?skill=&jobtype=Work. that;s it and i have mentioned Allloc+$l1 which it is not showing in the url

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first we have html error here. You can't use option tag without using select element.

```
<?php
$path13 = "Jobtype.php?skill=$s1&jobtype=$value5&Allloca=$l1";
?>
<select>
  <a href="<?= $path13 ?>"><option value="<?= $path13 ?>" selected><?= $value5 ?></option>
</select>
```

i didn't tried the code if it works let me know.

Comment: btw: I guess you are assigning value5 with $_GET["querystringofyours"]. if you don't then you can't get what you want without using it.

Comment: The problem is it goes to the mentioned url but with incomplete url

Comment: Sorry? I didn't get it. try to explain what you are struggling

Comment: I have created a url and in that I have passed three query string parameters but when the link goes to that url it shows only two parameters instead of three

Comment: it is because you are not letting the third variable. you need to show how do you define your variables.

Comment: this is the path where it redirects after clicking on it but the problem is after redirecting to this url page it is not showing third string parameter in the url   $path13 = "Jobtype.php?skill=$s1&jobtype=$value5&Allloca=$l1";

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"".url_encode($path13)."\"><option value=\"".url_encode($path13v)."\" Selected>$value5</option></a>";
```

You data must be quoted et use url_encode

Comment: Hi, when i click on the SELECT tag and OPTION tag's <a> it goes to the said url but incomplete: Jobtype.php?skill=&jobtype=Work. that;s it and i have mentioned Allloc+$l1 which it is not showing in the url

Comment: What's the value of jobtype? If you have black you have to use url_encode

Comment: I have created a url and in that I have passed three query string parameters but when the link goes to that url it shows only two parameters instead of three

Comment: urlencode() is not working. it is showing the same results

Comment: @user14026527 show your data and the code you test